# Help me understand understand how to access UINaviagtionController using this implementation

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

So I'm building an app and I am running through a few ViewControllers that don't need to know about each other, so I start off switching through views like so...

```
    // remove the previous view in order to load in the new view
    NSArray *sViews = [self.view subviews];
    [sViews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    // create the new view, in this case the user wishes to 
    BaseViewController *baseVC = [[BaseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BaseViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.baseViewController = baseVC;
    [baseVC release];

    // add the newly created view to the screen
    [self.view insertSubview:baseViewController.view atIndex:0];
```

The above is the view controller that I want the navigation controller to reside in. So within the .m of this view controller I created a UINavigationController as a member variable and named it navController. I then tried implementing a UINavigationController using the code below.

```
    UIViewController *control = [[BusinessDisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BusinessDisplayViewController" bundle: nil];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:control];
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

The problem I'm running into is two fold. First, when the BusinessDisplayViewController (below) is loaded there is a 20 pixel or so gap between my mapView and tableView that isn't there when I was loading it using `insertSubview:` not sure why that would be. Second, once I'm in BusinessDisplayViewController.m I'm not sure how to access the navigationController created in BaseViewController. Could someone explain why my view would be effected, how I could access the navigationController or if I'm even going about this the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationController` is designed for use in one of three possible contexts on iPhone:

1. As the app's root view controller, with its view added as a subview of the app's window.
2. As one of the viewControllers of a `UITabBarController`.
3. Presented as a full screen view controller via `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

In your case, the `UINavigationController` has configured itself for presentation as a subview of the window.  This is why you see the 20 pixel gap at the top.  Since the window object underlaps the status bar, `UINavigationController` offsets the position of its navigation bar by 20 pixels (or more, if you're on a phone call).

The standard way to use `UINavigationController` as your root view controller is to construct it as a property of your app delegate in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, and add its view as a subview of the window.  Then within any view controller you push onto your navigation stack, you can access the navigation controller object using `self.navigationController`.

Comment: So basically I need to scrap my way of thinking and just add the navigationController at the root of the app instead of trying to get cute with it :) Also the gap isn't at the top of my view, it's actually in between the mapView and the tableView.

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on what you mean by "get cute".  Just bear in mind that Apple designed the `UIViewController` framework to be used to manage "full screen" views.  If you're trying to create a navigation controller that only takes up part of the screen, you probably won't get that to work in iOS 4.  But if your navigation controller is full screen, and you just don't want it to be the root, you can always present it using `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you want your UINavigationController to be at the root level, Is there a specific reason for having your app setup this way? To answer your question though, you can access the variable by setting a [property](http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103) for it, then using the dot notation: `baseVC.navController`.

For the 20 pixel space problem, post your BaseViewController view related code. It is probably a bounds vs frame issue.

Comment: Not a great reason for it not being setup at the root level. Mainly I just have a keychain check and signup/login screens that I didn't feel needed to utilize the navigation controller (not passing any information to each other, no need to "go back" to any of them, etc). But when I am loading the mapView and tableView listing the businesses and the user clicks on the detailDisclosureButton a more detailed page of the business would come up and through the navController I could then "go back" to the map and list of businesses.

Comment: And where I created the navigation controller in BaseViewController, 
{
IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
}

(at)property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;

I also synthesized it in the .m I can easily access it in BaseViewController.m, but when I'm in BusinessDisplayViewController.m would I just create a new variable like so? BaseViewController *baseVC = [BaseViewController alloc];
 baseVC.navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent; 

Because that crashed on me.

Comment: Use a navigation controller from the start. You can set it to not display the nab bar and not display any toolbars, then not do an animation when pushing and you essentially have the same effect. I think it will solve your 20px thing too